# How to get showdown.js to work with text from database codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, showdown

I am using showdown.js and codeigniter. Once I have inserted code to database then, I should be able to preview the question from my database.

When I try and view it.

It shows error in firebug

> syntax error unterminated string literal

Javascript Showdown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    text = '<?php echo $output;?>',
    target = document.getElementById('output'),
    html = converter.makeHtml(text);
    target.innerHTML = html;

</script>
```

> **Question:** How to make showdown.js work with text from database in codeigniter

Controller

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $question = $this->results();


        $data['output'] = $question['question'];  

        print_r($question['question']); 


        $this->load->view('example_view', $data);
    }

    public function results() {
        $this->db->where('question_id', '1');
        $query = $this->db->get('question');

        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css');?>">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/showdown/dist/showdown.js');?>"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<textarea rows="10" class="form-control" id="editor"></textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div id="preview"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#editor").on('keyup', function(e) {
var text = document.getElementById('editor').value,
      target = document.getElementById('preview'),
      converter = new showdown.Converter(),
      html = converter.makeHtml(text);

    target.innerHTML = html;
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    text = '<?php echo $output;?>',
    target = document.getElementById('output'),
    html = converter.makeHtml(text);
    target.innerHTML = html;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you are attempting to plonk some "markup" via your view then have the script rewrite it back to the same location reformatted. It could work... Try wrapping the JS inside $(document).ready(function(){); Making sure of course that your "text" is making it to the page when your view source the resulting page.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown

Comment: Yep, already been and visited there prior to answering :) Ok so I cant edit my initial comment, so I'll restate it even more poorly this time... So you are squirting some markup into the JS and having it write the formatted text into the div...

Comment: I tried doing what you said wrapping  `$(document).ready(function(){);` still does not out put text from controller `$data['preview']`. to the div.

Comment: Well you are writing the content of $data['preview'] to the View so it's trying to land there , then the showdown js does it's thing, it should grab it and squirt it, reformatted into your preview div... So are you seeing the preview text from your controller appear in the JS in the resulting page via your browsers "view source" and eyeballing it.

Comment: I've not yet tried it but on paper it appears to have a chance of working...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I am not seeing any thing? But in fire bug the text is show I have added image in to question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128896/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-wolfgang1983).

Comment: You've changed things up a little, where is your view?

Answer (score 1):

In your tinkering without using the Database and just passing in test strings of various types, you would have noticed things like...

```
$preview = '###Test String\r\n## I am a Rabbit';
```

Works like a treat, whereas strings like (which you are producing from your DB)

```
 $preview = '###Test String
    ## I am a Rabbit';
```

Cause errors!
Well after a little hunting I found this neat trick.

To Format the string to be used in Javascript, you can use `json_encode()`.

You'll have to massage this to fit your situation...

```
$text = json_encode($text); // The string from your Table
echo "<script>var text={$text};</script>"; // Set it up as a var to pass to your JS
```

Or within the JS itself you can use something like, or how ever you want to pass
it in....

```
echo
"<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var text={$preview};
    var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    target = document.getElementById(\'output\'),
    html = converter.makeHtml(text);
    target.innerHTML = html;
});
</script>";
```

And the $(document).ready() wrapper does work as expected.

Comment: I if I have 4 spaces which triggers pre for `#Test String\r\nI am a Rabbit\r\n    <div class=""></div>`  what do I put in there because it's not detecting the 4 spaces I tried `#Test String\r\n\r\nI am a Rabbit\r\n\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class=""></div>`

Comment: As said here To create blocks of code you should indent it by four spaces. https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Showdown's-Markdown-syntax but not sure what to do on php side so out put can trigger pre tag that's why thought `&nbsp;` but did not work